# Simple Click Event?

Tags: javascript, jquery

What's the click event here?

http://jsfiddle.net/bgrins/ctkY3/

Why doesn't this work

```
$('#full').on('click', function(){
  alert('hello');
})
```

The goal here is if I click on a separate png, I can still open on the #full selector like this:

```
$('.png').on('click', function(){
  $('#full').click();
});
```

Comment: `.png` implies there is a html tag with `class='png'` that gets clicked on, which I could not see in your example, also you are missing the `;` on your `alert(` line

Comment: thanks, the $('.png') is just a theoretical selector. i am unable to upload the image to the fiddle, but it can essentially be anything. clicking an anchor tag with the class 'png' would still be along the same lines of the example

Comment: I'm not clear on what you're asking.  Are you asking how to get a function to execute if something is clicked? Or do you want to send a click to the particular spectrum.js object when you click something else? What do you mean "doesn't work"?

Comment: your original #full is hidden (display: none;) and you are not clicking on it

Comment: mark - 'doesn't work' refers to the click event not triggering. right now when you click #full, the color palette drops down. i want to mimic that behavior, but by clicking something else (i.e., the png).

cheery - thanks for the info. do you think removing the propagation would do anything?

Comment: @user3007294  Please read updated comment - your #full is hidden and that is why you are not clicking on it.

Comment: Firebug should have shown you that `id='full'` became `style='display:none;'`. There's no Element to click on.

Comment: thanks cheery. that seems to make sense. i'll have to mess with the selector a little bit and get it to display. thanks for the response.

+ phpglue - thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.spectrum()` is making `$('#full').css('display', 'none')`. Use the `containerClassName` property in the Object argument of `.spectrum()` and do your event according to that.

Answer (score -3):

You need to use the .trigger() method:

```
$('#full').trigger('click');
```

Comment: Are you saying that's different to `$('#full').click()`?